# I want to use the Android REST spring framework in order to get an Array of objects

Tags: android, spring, rest

I use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() and I found how to take one object in json.

This can be done :

```
MyClass result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyClass.class);
```

But what about if I have one list of objects? for example

```
[{"first" : "1", "second" : "2",},
 {"first" : "100", "second" : "200",}
]
```

or if I have something more complicated  like 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

Can somebody anwser me with some code examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
MyClass result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyClass.class);
```

To :

```
MyClass []result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyClass[].class);
```

**Update :**

You create a *pojo* for every node.

Example :

```
coord: {
        lon: -0.13,
        lat: 51.51
}
```

Become :

```
Class coord {
    int lon;
    int lat;
    setters/getters
}
```

**Code :**

```
List<MediaType> acceptableMedia = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMedia.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMedia);
HttpEntity< ?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());    
            // Wheater
ResponseEntity<Weather> responseEntity =   restTemplate.exchange("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk", HttpMethod.GET,  requestEntity, Weather.class);
Weather weather= responseEntity.getBody();
```

**N.B :** You can use http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ to generate your Pojo Class

Comment: Thank you. And if is something more complicated? like http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk Do you what I can do?

Comment: ok I will do the same for everything. so I will create all these classes but how I will link all these classes to one? and What I will write to getForObject() function? Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiadis yeah all class's will be member of one class  which is Weather class. see my edit again

Comment: @Makispapadopoulos if my response answer  your question don't forget to mark it as accepted

Comment: I'm not forgetting you. I just want to see if run first. I will test it today night. Thanks for the help!